# Prediction in Caffe - Exception: Input blob arguments do not match net inputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I'm using Caffe for classifying non-image data using a quite simple CNN structure. I've had no problems training my network on my HDF5-data with dimensions n x 1 x 156 x 12. However, I'm having difficulties classifying new data.

How do I do a simple forward pass without any preprocessing? My data has been normalized and have correct dimensions for Caffe (it's already been used to train the net). Below is my code and the CNN structure.

**EDIT:** I've isolated the problem to the function '_Net_forward' in pycaffe.py and found that the issue arises as the self.input dict is empty. Can anyone explain why that is? The set is supposed to be equal to the set coming from the new test data:

```
if set(kwargs.keys()) != set(self.inputs):
            raise Exception('Input blob arguments do not match net inputs.')
```

My code has changed a bit as I now use the IO methods for converting the data into datum (see below). In that way I've filled the kwargs variable with the correct data.

Even small hints would be greatly appreciated!

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Make sure that caffe is on the python path:
    caffe_root = ''  # this file is expected to be run from {caffe_root}
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'python')

    import caffe

    import os
    import subprocess
    import h5py
    import shutil
    import tempfile

    import sklearn
    import sklearn.datasets
    import sklearn.linear_model
    import skimage.io



    def LoadFromHDF5(dataset='test_reduced.h5', path='Bjarke/hdf5_classification/data/'):

        f   = h5py.File(path + dataset, 'r')
        dat = f['data'][:]
        f.close()   

        return dat;

    def runModelPython():
        model_file = 'Bjarke/hdf5_classification/conv_v2_simple.prototxt'
        pretrained = 'Bjarke/hdf5_classification/data/train_iter_10000.caffemodel'
        test_data = LoadFromHDF5()

        net = caffe.Net(model_file, pretrained)
        caffe.set_mode_cpu()
        caffe.set_phase_test()  

        user = test_data[0,:,:,:] 
        datum = caffe.io.array_to_datum(user.astype(np.uint8))
        user_dat = caffe.io.datum_to_array(datum)
        user_dat = user_dat.astype(np.uint8)
        out = net.forward_all(data=np.asarray([user_dat]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runModelPython()
```

**CNN Prototext**

```
name: "CDR-CNN"
layers {
  name: "data"
  type: HDF5_DATA
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "Bjarke/hdf5_classification/data/train.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
  include: { phase: TRAIN }
}
layers {
  name: "data"
  type: HDF5_DATA
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "Bjarke/hdf5_classification/data/test.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
  include: { phase: TEST }
}

layers {
  name: "feature_conv"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "data"
  top: "feature_conv"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 10
    kernel_w: 12
    kernel_h: 1
    stride_w: 1
    stride_h: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv1"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "feature_conv"
  top: "conv1"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 14
    kernel_w: 1
    kernel_h: 4
    stride_w: 1
    stride_h: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "pool1"
  type: POOLING
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_w: 1
    kernel_h: 3
    stride_w: 1
    stride_h: 3
  }
}
layers {
  name: "conv2"
  type: CONVOLUTION
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "conv2"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 120
    kernel_w: 1
    kernel_h: 5
    stride_w: 1
    stride_h: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "fc1"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "fc1"
  blobs_lr: 1
  blobs_lr: 2
  weight_decay: 1
  weight_decay: 0
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 84
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0
    }
  }
}
layers {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: ACCURACY
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include: { phase: TEST }
}
layers {
  name: "loss"
  type: SOFTMAX_LOSS
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Comment: Showing up the log file too would help us narrow the issue further

Comment: Just to let you know, I've been told it's not a bug on the tracker. I asked how to do it on the mailing list but got no reply so far https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/caffe-users/eEhSBlKcjpc/llQi9PTPAYsJ

Comment: Same issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/aojN_bmbg74

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is [the answer from Evan Shelhamer I got on the Caffe Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/aojN_bmbg74):

> `self._inputs` is indeed for the manual or "deploy" inputs as defined
>   by the input fields in a prototxt. To run a net with data layers in
>   through pycaffe, just call `net.forward()` without arguments. No need
>   to change the definition of your train or test nets.
>
> See for instance code cell [10] of the [Python LeNet example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/tutorial/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb).

In fact I think it's clearer in the [Instant Recognition with Caffe tutorial](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb), cell 6:

```
# Feed in the image (with some preprocessing) and classify with a forward pass.
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformer.preprocess('data', caffe.io.load_image(caffe_root + 'examples/images/cat.jpg'))
out = net.forward()
print("Predicted class is #{}.".format(out['prob'].argmax()))
```

In other words, to generate the predicted outputs as well as their probabilities using pycaffe, once you have trained your model, you have to first feed the data layer with your input, then perform a forward pass with `net.forward()`.

---

Alternatively, as pointed out in other answers, you can use a deploy prototxt that is similar to the one you use to define the trained network but removing the input and output layers, and add the following at the beginning (obviously adapting according to your input dimension):

```
name: "your_net"
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 250
```

That's what they use in the [CIFAR10 tutorial](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cifar10/cifar10_quick.prototxt).

<sup>(pycaffe really ought to be better documented…)</sup>

Comment: what if I want to use feature map as input and forward start from fc layer?

Answer (score 2):

Only due to my own experimental experience, it's not a very good idea to specify train and test net in one file using {PHASE} clause. I got many weird errors when I used net file like that, but when I used older version of net files which contain two files separately, train and test, it worked. However I was using caffe version in Nov 2014, perhaps there's some bug or compatible issues there.

Well, when the model is used for prediction, shouldn't there be a deploy file specifying the net structure? If you look at ImageNet you should find imagenet_deploy.prototxt there. Although deploy file is similar to train/test file, I heard it's a bit different due to some fillers. I don't know if it's the problem, but any discussion is welcome, I need to learn new caffe schema if there exist too

Answer (score 1):

```
Even small hints would be greatly appreciated!
```

I am stuck too so not much help, sorry. Might want to skip to the end.

`net.inputs` is a @property function which supposedly generated the names of the input layer(s).

```
@property
def _Net_inputs(self):
    return [list(self.blobs.keys())[i] for i in self._inputs]
```

Where `list(self.blobs.keys())` for you would be

```
['data', 'feature_conv', 'conv1', 'pool1', 'conv2', 'fc1', 'accuracy', 'loss']
```

Since `inputs` has to match `kwargs.keys() = ['data']` we can conclude that `net._inputs` should have been `[0]`. Somehow.

Since `_inputs` isn't used anywhere else in `pycaffe.py` I have a look at `_caffe.cpp`. Around line 222 it says

```
.add_property("_inputs", p::make_function(&Net<Dtype>::input_blob_indices,
    bp::return_value_policy<bp::copy_const_reference>()))
```

So `_inputs` are the `input_blob_indices` and it makes sense that these should be `[0]` for your network.

`input_blob_indices` in turn is simply a function that returns `net_input_blob_indices_` in `include/caffe/net.hpp`

```
inline const vector<int>& input_blob_indices() const { return net_input_blob_indices_; }
```

...which is only used in `src/caffe/net.cpp`, but I can't find it being defined or assigned anywhere.

I have tried with `type: Data` and `type: MemoryData` but that doesn't make a difference. What does work is using

```
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 227
input_dim: 227
```

...instead of a layer. In that case `net._inputs = [0]` and `net.inputs = ['data']` (actually `net._inputs` is a `caffe._caffe.IntVec object` but `list(net._inputs) = [0]`).

**TLDR**: It is starting to look a lot like a bug so I submitted it: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2246

P.s. it seems like you are converting ndarray to datum and then back again. Does this have a purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. This is what fixed it.

First, take the same prototext file as you used to train, remove the two data layers.

Then add the block as Mark's above

```
name: "Name_of_your_net"
input: "data"
input_dim: 64 
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 28
input_dim: 28
```

where my input_dim are for mnist, change them to your dim.

Everything works.

Comment: Yeah good answer, probably solves it for 90% of people. But sometimes you really need layers, e.g. to feed data into different parts of the network (like extra after the convolution), or different shapes of data. Anyway +1