# Passing arguments to the forward function in caffe

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I have found this line of code to send inputs to the network in caffe:

```
out = NET.forward(**{NET.inputs[0]: np.asarray([im_proc])})
```

I tried adapting this code for my work as follows:

```
out = net.forward(**{net.inputs[0]:im_proc})
```

where `im_proc = np.zeros((100,9))` (just for testing) but I get the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am unable to understand why I cant run the forward method this way. I am able to call `net.forward()` regularly though.

```
 In [32]: net.forward()
 Out[32]: 
 {'cross_entropy_loss': array(0.6027408838272095, dtype=float32),
 'l2_error': array(1.7882403135299683, dtype=float32)}
```

---

From the comments I understand that I am supposed to initialize the input array with possibly the `caffe.io.Transformer` function.

I tried the following loop:

```
for ix,in_ in enumerate(im_proc):
   caffe_in[ix] = caffe.io.Transformer.preprocess(net.inputs[0],in_)
   out = net.forward(**{net.inputs[0]:im_proc})
   print out
```

But this still causes the same error.

Comment: Clearly your `net.inputs` is empty, so there is no `0`th element.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for pointing me in the direction of a solution. Is there any reason the input array would be empty? The model definition seems fine.

Comment: I've no idea, try updating your question with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited as best as I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to switch out the prototext. The C++ code PyCaffe wraps around causes this behavior. This thread has the solution: [Prediction in Caffe - Exception: Input blob arguments do not match net inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124840/prediction-in-caffe-exception-input-blob-arguments-do-not-match-net-inputs)

Answer (score 0):

the `net` object is expecting a **list** of images as input, you supply only one image.

Try

```
out = net.forward(**{net.inputs[0]: [ im_proc ] })
```

Note the square brackets (`[]`) around `im_proc` converting it into a list containing a single image.

Comment: The suggestion is excellent, however caffe does a weird thing by crashing post this.

Comment: @shaunakde can you get caffe to print detailed log?